# Why am I getting a 500 error for this api request

Tags: php, ajax, api, guzzle

I am trying top use guzzle to get data from https://idf.intven.com/public_patents. The page loads data with AJAX by making request to https://idf.intven.com/public_patent_listing.json.

I am working on a another site for them that they want to use this data for so I am trying to grab this data with guzzle but I keep getting 500 errors.

```
    $this->client = new Client();
    $this->client->post( 'https://idf.intven.com/public_patent_listing.json', [
        'verify' => false,
        'json'    => [
        "report_type" => "public_patent_listing",
        "queryFields" => [],
        "filters" => [],"per_page" => 16,
        "from" => 0,
        "sort" => "issued_on",
        "sort_order" => "desc"
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: 500 is internal server error, which means , some  issue at server end, i havent tested your code, but if it is Syntax is correct then it is server side issue.

Comment: Maybe because you are using arrays instead of json objects

Comment: Its specific to my code because it works on the their site. They are doing something that I am not. how can I force json objects in PHP for guzzle?

Comment: @mynawaz you are right. When I use stdObject it works. Make it an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are using arrays instead of json objects. Change the square brackets to curly ones for main object and `json` object in it